# How can I process this array without huge amounts of code?

Tags: arrays, cobol

I'll start by admitting this is for my homework and I don't expect anything specific just a tip perhaps. The input file is just one 30 byte field that contains names. The output file is two fields 30 bytes each. I'll list the code to show what I mean by this. The program needs to read the input file putting the names into an array and then print them to the two fields in the output file. It would be simple enough if the out put file was like this:

```
name 1             name 2
name 3             name 4
etc...
```

but it's supposed to be:

```
name 1             name 55
name 2             name 56
....
name 54            name 108
```

I'm not quite understanding how I can code the program to do this without having 54 lines of code (1 for each line in the output). Well here's the code I have so far:

```
ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.                                        
INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.                                        
FILE-CONTROL.                                                

SELECT NAMELIST-FILE-IN                                  
    ASSIGN TO 'NAMELIST.SEQ'                             
    ORGANIZATION IS LINE SEQUENTIAL.                     

SELECT NAMELIST-FILE-OUT                                 
    ASSIGN TO 'NAMELIST.RPT'                             
    ORGANIZATION IS LINE SEQUENTIAL.                     

 DATA DIVISION.                                               
 FILE SECTION.                                                

 FD NAMELIST-FILE-IN.                                         
    01 NAME-IN                       PIC X(30).                  

 FD NAMELIST-FILE-OUT.                                        
    01 NAME-OUT                      PIC X(60).                  

WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.                                     
    01 ARE-THERE-MORE-RECORDS        PIC X(3)  VALUE 'YES'.      
    01 PAGE-CTR                      PIC 99    VALUE ZERO.       
    01 SUB                           PIC 999   VALUE 1.          
    01 LEFT-NAME                     PIC 99    VALUE 54.         
    01 RIGHT-NAME                    PIC 9(3)  VALUE 108.        

01 WS-DATE.                                                  
    05 RUN-YEAR                  PIC XX.                     
    05 RUN-MONTH                 PIC XX.                     
    05 RUN-DAY                   PIC XX.                     

01 HEADING-LINE.                                             
    05                           PIC X(15) VALUE SPACES.     
    05                           PIC X(20)                   
        VALUE 'NAME LIST REPORT'.                            
    05 HL-DATE.                                              
        10  DAY-HL               PIC XX.                     
        10                       PIC X     VALUE '/'.        
        10  MONTH-HL             PIC XX.                     
        10                       PIC X     VALUE '/'.        
        10  YEAR-HL              PIC XX.                     
    05                           PIC X(3)  VALUE SPACES.     
    05                           PIC X(5)  VALUE 'PAGE'.     
    05  PAGE-NUMBER-HL           PIC Z9    VALUE 1.          

01 DETAIL-LINE.                                              
    05 NAME-LEFT                 PIC X(30).                  
    05 NAME-RIGHT                PIC X(30).                  

01 NAME-ARRAY.                                               
    05 NAME-X   OCCURS 108       PIC X(30).                  

PROCEDURE DIVISION.                                          
100-MAIN.                                                    
    OPEN INPUT NAMELIST-FILE-IN                              
    OPEN OUTPUT NAMELIST-FILE-OUT                            

    ACCEPT WS-DATE FROM DATE.                                
        MOVE RUN-MONTH TO MONTH-HL                           
        MOVE RUN-DAY TO DAY-HL                               
        MOVE RUN-YEAR TO YEAR-HL                             

    PERFORM 200-ACCEPT-INPUT                                 


    CLOSE NAMELIST-FILE-IN                                   
    CLOSE NAMELIST-FILE-OUT                                  
    STOP RUN.                                                

200-ACCEPT-INPUT.                                            
    PERFORM UNTIL SUB > 108                                  
        READ NAMELIST-FILE-IN                                
        MOVE NAME-IN TO NAME-X (SUB)                         
        ADD 1 TO SUB                                         
    END-PERFORM                                              

    PERFORM 300-PRINT-ONE-PAGE.                              

300-PRINT-ONE-PAGE.                                          
    WRITE NAME-OUT FROM HEADING-LINE                         
        AFTER ADVANCING PAGE                                 
    ADD 1 TO PAGE-CTR
```

Here's the final code for this program if anyone is interested in seeing it.

```
ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.                                            
INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.                                            
FILE-CONTROL.                                                    

    SELECT NAMELIST-FILE-IN                                      
        ASSIGN TO 'NAMELIST.SEQ'                                 
        ORGANIZATION IS LINE SEQUENTIAL.                         

    SELECT NAMELIST-FILE-OUT                                     
        ASSIGN TO 'NAMELIST.RPT'                                 
        ORGANIZATION IS LINE SEQUENTIAL.                         

DATA DIVISION.                                                   
FILE SECTION.                                                    

FD NAMELIST-FILE-IN.                                             
01 NAME-IN                       PIC X(30).                      

FD NAMELIST-FILE-OUT.                                            
01 NAME-OUT                      PIC X(80).                      

WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.                                         
01 ARE-THERE-MORE-RECORDS        PIC X(3)  VALUE 'YES'.          
01 PAGE-CTR                      PIC 99    VALUE ZERO.           
01 SUB                           PIC 999.                        
01 SUB2                          PIC 999.                        
01 LEFT-NAME                     PIC 99    VALUE 54.             
01 RIGHT-NAME                    PIC 9(3)  VALUE 108.            

01 WS-DATE.                                                      
    05 RUN-YEAR                  PIC XX.                         
    05 RUN-MONTH                 PIC XX.                         
    05 RUN-DAY                   PIC XX.                         

01 HEADING-LINE.                                                 
    05                           PIC X(26) VALUE SPACES.         
    05                           PIC X(35)                       
        VALUE 'NAME LIST REPORT'.                                
    05 HL-DATE.                                                  
        10  DAY-HL               PIC XX.                         
        10                       PIC X     VALUE '/'.            
        10  MONTH-HL             PIC XX.                         
        10                       PIC X     VALUE '/'.            
        10  YEAR-HL              PIC XX.                         
    05                           PIC X(3)  VALUE SPACES.         
    05                           PIC X(5)  VALUE 'PAGE'.         
    05  PAGE-NUMBER-HL           PIC Z9.                         

01 DETAIL-LINE.                                                  
    05 NAME-LEFT                 PIC X(40).                      
    05 NAME-RIGHT                PIC X(40).                      

01 NAME-ARRAY.                                                   
    05 NAME-X   OCCURS 108       PIC X(30).                      

PROCEDURE DIVISION.                                              
100-MAIN.                                                        
    OPEN INPUT NAMELIST-FILE-IN                                  
    OPEN OUTPUT NAMELIST-FILE-OUT                                

    ACCEPT WS-DATE FROM DATE.                                    
        MOVE RUN-MONTH TO MONTH-HL                               
        MOVE RUN-DAY TO DAY-HL                                   
        MOVE RUN-YEAR TO YEAR-HL                                 

    PERFORM UNTIL ARE-THERE-MORE-RECORDS = 'NO'                  
        PERFORM 200-ACCEPT-INPUT                                 
    END-PERFORM                                                  

    CLOSE NAMELIST-FILE-IN                                       
    CLOSE NAMELIST-FILE-OUT                                      
    STOP RUN.                                                    

200-ACCEPT-INPUT.                                                
    INITIALIZE NAME-ARRAY                                        
    MOVE 1 TO SUB                                                

    PERFORM UNTIL SUB > 108 OR ARE-THERE-MORE-RECORDS = 'NO'     
        READ NAMELIST-FILE-IN                                    
            AT END                                               
                MOVE 'NO' TO ARE-THERE-MORE-RECORDS              
                MOVE SPACES TO NAME-IN                           
        END-READ                                                 
        MOVE NAME-IN TO NAME-X (SUB)                             
        ADD 1 TO SUB                                             

    END-PERFORM                                                  

    PERFORM 300-PRINT-ONE-PAGE.                                  

300-PRINT-ONE-PAGE.                                              
    ADD 1 TO PAGE-CTR                                            
    MOVE PAGE-CTR TO PAGE-NUMBER-HL                              
    WRITE NAME-OUT FROM HEADING-LINE                             
        AFTER ADVANCING PAGE                                     

    MOVE SPACES TO DETAIL-LINE                                   
    WRITE NAME-OUT FROM DETAIL-LINE                              
        AFTER ADVANCING 1                                        

    PERFORM VARYING SUB FROM 1 BY 1 UNTIL SUB > 54               
        MOVE NAME-X (SUB) TO NAME-LEFT                           
        COMPUTE SUB2 = SUB + 54                                  
        MOVE NAME-X (SUB2) TO NAME-RIGHT                         
        WRITE NAME-OUT FROM DETAIL-LINE                          
            AFTER ADVANCING 1                                    
    END-PERFORM.
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Printing in two columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14679229/printing-in-two-columns)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I must apologize, I cannot think of a way to guide you without giving away the answer.  I guess this is a spoiler alert.

One possible method you could use would be to add a variable `SUB2` to `Working-Storage` and...

```
Perform Varying SUB From 1 By 1 Until SUB > 54
  Move NAME-X(SUB) to NAME-LEFT
  Compute SUB2 = SUB + 54
  MOVE NAME-X(SUB2) to NAME-RIGHT
  Write NAME-OUT from DETAIL-LINE After Advancing 1 Line
End-Perform
```

This is kind of kludgy and ties you to an array of 108 elements.  You could use a record counter that you increment by 1 for each record read and then compute the values I show hardcoded in the sample above (54 is simply half of 108).

I don't show the page break logic, so perhaps I didn't give the whole show away.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: That helps greatly :) No worries about it giving it away. I had been thinking about this for a couple hours and started to get a headache. I was thinking way outside the box on this one lol. As far as being tied to an array of 108 elements, the assignment actually requires the output page to be 54 detail lines so it has to be 108 elements. I'll just have to move zeros to SUB and SUB2 after the perform. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I would have 2 arrays.

One containing the whole file.

```
01 DETAIL-LINE-ARRAY.
    02 DETAIL-LINE OCCURS 54.                                              
        05 NAME-LEFT                 PIC X(30).                  
        05 NAME-RIGHT                PIC X(30).
```

Another like you did with `NAME-ARRAY`

Then I would populate first the `DETAIL-LINE-ARRAY`.

I would read twice DETAIL-LINE-ARRAY to fill `NAME-ARRAY`

Then you can read sequentially `NAME-ARRAY`

==========================================================================

Another solution:

You can read the file twice. While the first read, you take care only of the left name and populate `NAME-ARRAY`.

While the second reading, you take care only of the right name and continue to populate `NAME-ARRAY`.

After the first and second read, you can read your array `NAME-ARRAY`.

==========================================================================

There is a problem with both last solutions : you have to know how much lines contains your file. Yep, you can have dynamic programming in cobol too :-)

You have to use `SORT`.

In `FILE SECTION` add

```
SD  SORT-WORK
01  SORT-RECORD.
    05  SR-ORDER      PIC 9(09).
    05  SR-NAME       PIC X(30).
```

In your `PROCEDURE DIVISION` add (in pseude-code, you'll need to add some variables in your working storage section.

```
      SORT SORT-WORK
           ASCENDING SORT-ORDER
           INPUT PROCEDURE IS 1000-INPUT
           OUTPUT PROCEDURE IS 2000-OUTPUT

    1000-INPUT SECTION.
         MOVE 0 TO I.
         PERFORM until end-of-file of NAMELIST-FILE-IN  
           ADD 1 TO I
           READ left-name
           MOVE I TO SORT-ORDER
           MOVE left-name TO SR-NAME
    * This operation populates the sort file...
           RELEASE SORT-RECORD
         END-PERFORM.
    
         PERFORM until end-of-file of NAMELIST-FILE-IN
           ADD 1 TO I
           READ right-name
           MOVE I TO SORT-ORDER
           MOVE right-name TO SR-NAME
    * This operation populates the sort file...
           RELEASE SORT-RECORD     
         END-PERFORM.
    
         MOVE I TO WS-NB-NAMES.
    
     2000-OUTPUT SECTION.
         PERFORM VARYING I FROM 1 BY 1 UNTIL I > WS-NB-NAMES
* This operation returns the "next" record. It begins by the first, second...
           RETURN SORT-RECORD
           MOVE SR-NAME TO NAME-LEFT
           RETURN SORT-RECORD
           MOVE SR-NAME TO NAME-RIGHT
           WRITE NAMELIST-FILE-OUT FROM DETAIL-LINE
         END-PERFORM.
```

You [have some example here for SORT](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1539290)

Have fun !

Comment: I think I see what your getting at there but it might be a little beyond what we've been taught so far. I do appreciate you taking the time to answer though. I was able to get it to work using what cschneid wrote and after adding in a little more code myself. I'm going to post an answer with what my final code was to get the program to run correctly.